# Visualize how a function varies as its parameters vary

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm quite new to *Mathematica*, so maybe i havent figured out the right help file to look or the right function. I apologize if thats the case, but I would like to be pointed in the right direction if possible.

Say I have the following function `q t E^(B2 + B1 t^n)`, where everything is a constant except for `t`. How would I plot the function for the different parameters `B1`, `B2`, `q`, and `n` if I am just interested in seeing how the function changes with respect to those parameters? I don't have any data per se, its just interest in seeing how a function changes.

Comment: Look up `Manipulate`. That will probably help in the long run. But perhaps you should figure out how to `Plot` the function with some chosen parameters first. Look up basic *Mathematica* syntax (for instance, `exp^( stuff)` should be `Exp[ stuff ]`), look at the documentation for `Plot`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
r = 2;
Manipulate[
 Plot[q t E^(Subscript[B, 2] + Subscript[B, 1] t^n), {t, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50],
 {q, -r, r},
 {Subscript[B, 1], -r, r},
 {Subscript[B, 2], -r, r},
 {n, -r, r}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Recommend avoiding the use of subscripts as variable names.